# Number of characters for a finite group of order 57

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, representation-theory, characters

So this is an old prelim question and I have some questions. Let me first state the pre lim problem. If $G$ is a nonabelian group of order 57 how many 1-dimensional characters does $G$ have.

Now I know that up to isomorphism there is only one such group $G$ which can be realized as a semi direct product of $Z_{19}$ and $Z_3$. My question is regarding the definition of character. I've seen it defined as maps from $G\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^\times$ or generally to maps $G\rightarrow F$ where $F$ is a field, which is the correct definition? If its the first case how do I count such maps. Sorry I'm unfamiliar with representation/character theory, so assume that I'm completely uninformed on this matter. I was thinking of defining the maps into $\mathbb{C}^\times$ on $Z_{19}$ and $Z_3$ separately and combing them somehow, but now sure of my constructions. There's probably some theorems/lemmas from representation theory that would make this easier, but again I'm not familiar with them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For a homomorphism $G\to \mathbb{C}^\times$ with $G$ a finite group, the image must be isomorphic to a cyclic group, so you can classify surjective homomorphisms $G\to Z_n$ for varying $n$.

Comment: Without any other clarification, character presumably means "trace of a representation $\rho:G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})"$.

Comment: There is indeed a result that would make this easier, namely that $1$-dimensional (complex) characters are the same as those for the abelianization of the group, which you know. Also, the characters of a cyclic group are easy to describe.

Comment: Oh nice. In our case the abelianization would simply be just $Z_3$ correct? And there are only 3 such maps(trivial map, identity map, and antipodal map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For counting (complex) linear characters, you don't even have to construct them all. A standard result in character theory, see for instance Isaacs (1994, [Corollary 2.23](https://books.google.com/books?id=MeE7BFXwQroC&&pg=PA25)), says that such number equals the index of the commutator subgroup $\lvert G : G' \rvert$. Hence it equals three, as you've already know.

Comment: This is good to know. Thanks Orat.